# What reason, if any, to keep unused parameters in a function? Are these parameters even unused?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, ecmascript-5

I'm relatively new on my journey of understanding Javascript and am currently using it to mod a game. In that game there are cards which are dealt out, which are effectively functions that return a number of values:

```js
// !LOCNS:galactic_war
define(["module", "shared/gw_common", "cards/gwc_start"], function(
  module,
  GW,
  GWCStart
) {
  var CARD = { id: /[^\/]+$/.exec(module.id).pop() };

  return {
    visible: function(params) {
      return false;
    },
    summarize: function(params) {
      return "!LOC:Bionic Augmentation Commander Of Neutralizing";
    },
    icon: function(params) {
      return "coui://ui/main/game/galactic_war/shared/img/red-commander.png";
    },
    describe: function(params) {
      return "!LOC:The Bionic Augmentation Commander Of Neutralizing loadout contains one data bank but increases the Commander's fire rate by 100%, decreases Uber Cannon energy usage by 75%, increases health by 200%, and increases speed by 650%.";
    },
    hint: function() {
      return {
        icon:
          "coui://ui/main/game/galactic_war/gw_play/img/tech/gwc_commander_locked.png",
        description:
          "!LOC:Commander Invictus has this powerful loadout hidden away on the Entara system."
      };
    },
    deal: function(system) {
      return {
        params: {
          allowOverflow: true
        },
        chance: 0
      };
    }
  };
});
```

None of these functions use their parameter, so my question is whether there's some reason for the parameter to still exist? I've seen discussions online about whether to put an underscore in front of an unused parameter, but I'm not sure if that indicates some reason for such things to be there, or if that's because "it might do something so mark it and move on to be safe".

Also, as I mentioned, I'm new to JS, so if that parameter is somehow used in the return of the value I am unaware.

I guess I'm just looking to understand why these parameters might exist here. Why is `visible` a function at all and not just `visible: false`? This in itself suggests I'm missing something key.

I understand that due to dependencies I might not be showing enough to provide a comprehensive answer, but as this is code from a game I can only post a bit. I'm just looking to get pointed in the right direction so I can understand these things.

Comment: I clean and remove unused parameters ASAP to help with code understanding. They are unnecessary complications

Comment: Generally you want to trim everything unused in a code. But when you are just starting to write your code, it might make sense to add a filler "param" parameter on a function, just in case. One might forget to remove this filler parameter later on.

Comment: @mario_sunny I'm not sure I understand. If you don't care about the first parameter but you do care about the second, why would you not just remove the first and feed the second through as the first instead?

Comment: @AbanaClara when you say "just in case", what do you mean?

Comment: @Quitch just in case that function accepts a parameter later on.